# How to fix dropdown container for Mac when it works fine on other platforms like windows?

Tags: html, css, border, responsive

[Here I created a dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knprt.png) using html and css it looks perfect on windows and linux but it looks like it hasnt been applied any css when I see it on mac browser it looks like the following image on mac browser i dont know how to fix this??

Comment: Any styling you've been able to achieve up to now has been through sheer luck. This is why it's important to test multiple browsers/OS's early on before you do too much work. You cannot reliably style UI elements like drop downs or scroll bars. They always have different aesthetics across OS's, browsers and devices. This is why there's a whole world of making custom drop downs and scroll bars.

Comment: You can still do this, but you'll to make custom components. It's a common practice.

Comment: style it with [`appearance: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)